# okHttp3 keep-alive connection not working

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using okhttp3 with retrofit2 to fetch json files. I tried everything to use keep-Alive connection to make data download faster but nothing seems to work.

I have implemented interceptor and have added keep-alive header. But it seems that it just doesn't want to work. Can someone please look into my code and tell me what I am doing wrong here? This is my code :

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
ConnectionPool connectionPool = new ConnectionPool(3, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.connectionPool(connectionPool)
                .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.interceptors().add(logging);
        httpClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @NotNull
            @Override
            public Response intercept(@NotNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();

                // Customize the request
                Request request = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
                        .method(original.method(), original.body())
                        .build();

                try {
                    Response response = chain.proceed(request);
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                            response.close();
                            connectionPool.evictAll();
                            Log.d("okokok", "evict");
                            return chain.proceed(request);
                        } else {
                            // Customize or return the response
                            Log.d("okokok", "return response");
                            return response;
                        }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    connectionPool.evictAll();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            }
        });

        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()

                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(client)
                .build();

        postService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);
```

According to this code, header should contain Keep-Alive and connection shouldn't close for at least one minute.

I also checked my server and found that it does accept Keep-Alive header and in GTMatrix test also it showed that Keep-Alive is indeed working on my server. But due to some reason the android app keeps closing connection and every time I load a new file it takes time to make new connection to server.

I tried it with Firebase realtime database and saved my json data. And when I queried from there, I was astonished to see data download speed was exactly the same as retrofit for first query but after first query, every other query took milliseconds to load data. which means 10 to 20 times faster than retrofit.

One thing I would like to add here is, that I am using Glide to load images from server and Glide seems to use Keep-Alive setting quiet well because Glide load images very efficiently, without delay at all. So this slow downloading problem seems only to be with okhttp3 + Retrofit.

Can anyone look into it and let me know what I am doing wrong here? I have been working on this problem for 2 weeks now and still haven't found solution. I read every stackoverflow question related to this problem but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Okay, I noticed that if I load a file and within 3-4 seconds if i load another file then it takes few milliseconds, however if I load files after 10 seconds or more then connection closes and reopens again for each file and thus takes a few seconds more.

Answer (score 4):

Al right, this code is working fine, I found out that my host has a limit of 5 seconds on keepAliveTimeout, that's why KeepAlive works only for 5 seconds and after that connection closes. No matter what I do code wise can't change this unless I change my host.